# Obtaining wrong element of an object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

hey new to coding so please be gentle. I'm going through a testing website that supplies its own arguments and the the following code is returning the wrong element and I can't figure out why. Where am I going wrong? I'm trying to return the final element of the array contained within the object.

> If the array contains one item, it should return that one item. If the array contains an empty string, it should return an empty string. If the object is empty, it should return an empty string.

This is the code I've got so far but it fails when being passed one of the arguments by the test returning `r` instead of `up`:

```js
const movieData = {
  "studio": "Disney",
  "mainCharacter": "Carl Fredricksen",
  "films": ["Up"]
}

function lastElement(obj) {
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0)
    return "";
  else {
    let arr = Object.values(obj)[0];
    if (arr.length === 0)
      return "";
    else
      return arr[arr.length - 1]
  }
}

console.log(lastElement(movieData))
```

Comment: Welcome. As you can see I've fixed up your post to 1) present the problem before the code, and 2) show the code as a functioning snippet demo. That's done easily using the editor. See [ask] for more tips, and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: The instructions aren't very clear. The first two conditions refer to an array, the last one refers to an object. Which is it?

Comment: `Object.values(obj)[0];` is going to return "Disney" and then you are reading the last character of the string so it is "y"

Comment: Somewhere you need to determine whether your property is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the third object that is `let arr = Object.values(obj)[2];`

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following function:

```
function getLastValue(obj) {
  const arr = []; 
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    arr.push(value);
  });
  return arr[arr.length-1]
}
```

I think it does the job!